# How do I match an object in one camera to the same object in another camera using stereo vision, with opencv and python?

Tags: python, opencv, camera, computer-vision, stereo-3d

I have performed stereo calibration and can undistort and rectify the images obtained from both my left and right cameras. I am running an object detection algorithm on each camera to identify different objects of the same shape and color. I can compute the disparity between the two images and manually calculate the depth/distance to the objects since I am able to identify a boudary box for each detected object. I want to automate this, but will need to ensure that a detected object on the left image matches with my detected object on the right image. Provided I have my stereo camera parameters and the location of bounding box of each object in each image, is there a OpenCV function that can easily allow me to match the same objects with each other so that I can automatically calculate the distance ?
An example of the two images (sorry I couldn't provide real photos):
[image]

What I have tried:
I am currently looking into feature matching algorithms such as SIFT and ORB but my concern is that since I have multiple objects of the same shape and color, there will be multiple similar matches. I have tried filtering based on area of the bounding boxes but this will not work in all cases since I can have two different objects with a similar detected area.

Comment: Do the three objects have the same distance to the camera, or can one be closer than the other?

Comment: One can be closer than the other: in the image, object 1 is closer (hence it appears larger)

Comment: Once you have rectifies the images, sane objects must be in the same row in the images (horizontal epipolar lines). If in addition you can use sone assumptions about distances and sizes this might be the solution.

Comment: Thank you @Micka. Using area of the detection and distances to match proved to be quite challenging, since there are objects that can be quite close to each other. Having sub-optimal calibration didn't help as well.

Comment: Can you tell more about your use-case? If image objects have similar size, appearance and position, can their object size and distance vary strongly?!? If not, there can imho be only one good matching, because if 2 object matches are switched, you would measure one object very close and the other one very far away?!?

Comment: Have a look at this example if 2 objects and the 2 possible matchings/distances: https://ibb.co/59vV5VQ does this show the problem?